# Website not load fully in webview Android Studio

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to show the website with url but when its loaded, Some Website load fully and some of websites not load properly as load in chrome or any external browser. I am stuck here and didn't understand how to solve it.

```
public class UresultDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;

    public UresultDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uresult_detail, container, false);
        String url= getArguments().getString("url");
        webView=(WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.UniversityDetailWebview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding User-agent header to your requests

Answer (score 0):

Attach a WebViewClient with the web view and implement on received error event and see if there is any error occurred during loading.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError)